# How to disable collation

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have come across two methods to fix the collation conflict on two databases with different collation.

1. set the same collation on both databases
2. specify the collation in the select statement

I am wondering if there is any server-wide setting to ignore the collation in select statements?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 r2

Answer (score 1):

you cant ignore collation.
The collation basically indicates how the comparison is going to be done (like if A = a)

you will need to define the collation on your where clause like this:

```
SELECT Column1
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'search'
```

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL, you can set this per-connection, or in the server config.

Per-connection: SET NAMES 'charset_name' COLLATE 'collation_name';